# react navigation How to close the DrawerNavigator nested StackNavigator？

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to close the Drawer on `screen: ExportClues`, but it is not working.

**This is my code.**

```
const Drawer = DrawerNavigator( {
  Navigators: {
            screen: Navigators
         },
     {
           initialRouteName: 'Navigators',
           drawerWidth: Metrics.screenWidth - 95,
           drawerPosition: 'right',
           contentComponent:  MenuNavigator 
      }
})


const Navigators = StackNavigator({
     ...screen
})

const MenuNavigator = StackNavigator({
       ExportClues: {
                 screen: ExportClues,
        },
       ...other screen
})
```

**It is ExportClues Component:**

```
export default class index extends Component {

                   render() {
                        return(
                               <View
                                        style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#ffffff'}}
                                 >
                                      <TouchableOpacity
                                          onPress={()=>{
                                             this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose');
                                              // It is not work
                                             }}
                                         >
                                      <TouchableOpacity/>
                                </View>
                         )
                     }
 }
```

Sorry, My english is very poor.

How to get `MenuNavigator` Parent Navigator as `DrawerNavigator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the link you provided, you are trying to include the Drawer component incorrectly: 
You write
    import Drawer from './drawer'
and try to use component
    
but your drawer.js file is exporting "CustomerManagerDrawerNavigator"

```
export default CustomerManagerDrawerNavigator;
```

which means your code should be
    import CustomerManagerDrawerNagivator from './drawer'
and your component should be called as 
     
in the render() function.

If you want to use DrawerNavigator you need to to change your

```
const MenuNavigator = StackNavigator({
```

to

```
const MenuNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
```

to close the drawer while in ExportClues, you would call

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('DrawerClose'); // close drawer
```

which I see you have but you aren't passing any navigationOptions to in your Navigator configuration, so you don't have access to the navigate function. You need something like the code below:

```
navigationOptions: ({navigation}) => ({
 .../*Your navigation options here */
}),
```

to pass navigation as a prop to your open Drawer

I would review the React-Navigation homepage for DrawerNavigator located at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/drawer for more details or if possible post a link to a working repository

Comment: Hi , Thank you for your answer! But it is can't solve ，you can help me with the demo？Thanks [https://snack.expo.io/SJ1LIcjRW](https://snack.expo.io/SJ1LIcjRW)

Comment: I've updated the answer above to point out issues in your App.js and Drawer.js file that need correcting.